# Login in function npgsql postgres

Tags: c#, sql, database, postgresql, npgsql

Hey i wanted to create a function to test my login but i don't know why the test tells me that the password is wrong even if i check variables , it always return a 0 ,

```
drop function u_login
create or replace function u_Login (username character varying(150),passwords int)
returns int as $$
begin


        if  (select count(*) from users where user_name=username and password=passwords) > 0
    then return 1;
        else return 0;
    end if ;
end
$$
language plpgsql
---test login---
select * from u_login('USER2',123456789)
```

i have a question too can i do a role like admin and normal user that can be identified in the login ?

thank you for helping

Comment: Works for me, once I create the table and add semicolons to your commands.  Although it is a horrible way to handle passwords.

Comment: any ideas how to handle the passwords?

Comment: pgcrypto extension offers bf hashing with an adjustable work factor.